# Python exceptions

Tags: python, exception

Is there a way to catch exceptions that happen during interpreter shutdown?

I have a gui application, and sometimes I get a thread error during interpreter shutdown, but I can only see this exception when I start the program from cmd.exe in the shell. I would like to log this exception into one of my log files, but I can't find a way to first catch it.

Comment: Could you provide further context? You get an exception when you run something from the shell, but.... when running in a GUI you still get it? What logging/handling is the GUI doing itself that's different from you launching whatever it is you're doing directly etc...?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I suspect I still get that exception, but there is no indication of it when running from gui. I can only read the exception message when starting from shell(cmd.exe). I'm using wxpython for my GUI framework. The error message reads like this: <code>Exception in thread Thread-35 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):</code>

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to overwrite [`sys.excepthook()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) with your own function to write the exception somewhere else than to stderr.